# Swift -Enum Redeclaration Error after updating to Xcode 11.4, Swift 5.2

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have an enum that worked fine in Xcode 11.3, Swift 5.1. I just graded to Xcode 11.4 Swift 5.2 and now I get a redeclaration error:

[image]

[image]

I did a global search and there aren't any other enums with the same name nor any other classes or enums that use the method. It never occurred prior to my upgrade. I did a clean, deep clean, and cleared out derived data.

How can I fix this error?

```
enum ActivityType: String {

    case north
    case south
    case east
    case west
    case up
    case down
    case still

    static func value(from raw: String?) -> ActivityType {
        switch raw {
        case ActivityType.north.rawValue():
            return .north
        case ActivityType.south.rawValue():
            return .south
        case ActivityType.east.rawValue():
            return .east
        case ActivityType.west.rawValue():
            return .west
        case ActivityType.up.rawValue():
            return .up
        case ActivityType.down.rawValue():
            return .down
        case ActivityType.still.rawValue():
            return .still
        default:
            return .still
        }
    }

    func rawValue() -> String { // error occurs here
        switch self {
        case .north:
            return "north"
        case .south:
            return "south"
        case .east:
            return "east"
        case .west:
            return "west"
        case .up:
            return "up"
        case .down:
            return "down"
        case .still:
            return "still"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `func rawValue()` at all when it does the same as would be automatically generated?

Comment: @Arkku I inherited this project from someone and it was code from the previous developer. I have no idea why they did it that and never knew it was done that way until I encountered the error.

Comment: the problem is that it conflicts with the RawRepresentable property rawValue. You just need to rename your method to anything other than rawValue

Comment: Just remove that method and use the rawValue property without parentheses

Comment: @LeoDabus that explains it. Before you added the comment I changed the name inside the file and it worked. I didn't know why. But thank you very much for the insight :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `enum` already has `String` as the raw value type, you have an autogenerated `rawValue` property. It conflicts with your `rawValue()` function. However, it is unnecessary, since you can just use the autogenerated code:

```
enum ActivityType: String {

    case north, south, east, west, up, down, still

    static func value(from rawValue: String?) -> ActivityType {
        guard let rawValue = rawValue, let activityType = ActivityType(rawValue: rawValue) else {
            return .still
        }
        return activityType
    }

}
```

The above does the same as your code. Of course even that is largely unnecessary, since you could just use `ActivityType(rawValue: myString) ?? .still` directly.

Comment: OP, you may want to use Swift's built-in "ActivityType(rawValue: rawValue)" instead of your own value function which will return a default value if you make a typo. For example ActivityType.value(from: "wst") will give you a "still" value.

Comment: You can have this be an `init` overload. I put that in another answer.

Comment: @elliott-io I reread your other comments and you was 100% correct, that’s why I deleted my answer. I didn’t realize you pointed out the way I had my answer I was just using another version of rawValue which was pointless. But as I said I inherited this project from someone else so .... Anyhow thanks for the help and the advice. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Happy to help, @LanceSamaria! Happy coding :-)

Comment: @Arkku thanks for the help! Your answer simplified things :)

Answer (score 0):

```swift
protocol RawRepresentableWithDefault: RawRepresentable {
  static var `default`: Self { get }
}

extension RawRepresentableWithDefault {
  init(rawValue: RawValue?) {
    self = rawValue.flatMap(Self.init) ?? .default
  }
}
```

```swift
enum ActivityType: String {
  case north, south, east, west, up, down, still
}

extension ActivityType: RawRepresentableWithDefault {
  static let `default` = still
}
```